# how can i load js or css files to bundle from external location outside of application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, web-optimization

I have a requirement where i want application to load all css and js file from a share directory, i researched and found that bundle config includes directory from virtual application path only, so is there any way i can load it from external drives or folder? Or is there anything else i can use to meet my requirement.
i need something like this

```
  StyleBundle scriptBundleshare = new StyleBundle("\\diectory\folder");     

  scriptBundleshare.IncludeDirectory(pathToshare, "*.css");
  bundles.Add(scriptBundleshare.OrdinalPositionOrdered());
```

Comment: pathshare is shared location, like in this case its "\\diectory\folder"

Answer (score 0):

You can read directory all file name then
iterator loop And Create 
Html tag One StringBuffer or any Other Way And Print Html File

Comment: hi, thanks for response, can you give me example please?

Comment: i dont have uses Asp.net but i have used Java Example